# Unison ignore all files in path except for html files

Tags: unison

I want to be able to ignore all files under any directory named `build` except for `.html` files.

So for example:

**Ignored**:

```
MyProject/build/manifest.xml
MyProject/Package1/build/code.java
```

**Not Ignored**

```
MyProject/src/manifest.xml
MyProject/build/index.html
```

Currently I have tried these rules (and many besides):

```
ignore = Regex ^.*(build)+.+\.+.{1,5}$
ignorenot = Regex ^.*(build)+.*(\.html)$
```

However they don't work; how can I accomplish this?